# How can I set the value of a native element in Angular, using Renderer2?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular-renderer2

I'd like to set the innerText/innerHTML/textContent of a nativeElement?

```
this.render.setValue(this.nativeCloneLi.querySelector('.down .inn'), timeVal);
```

where **timeVal** is a string

the element is correctly selected, but **setValue** seems not working at all

Comment: How do you create `nativeCloneLi`?

Comment: Using an ElementRef **instance.nativeElement**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use `renderer.setProperty()` instead of `renderer.setValue()`.

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div #el></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '<h1>Hello world</h1>');
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer-setproperty-innerhtml)

Comment: Should we also use renderer if we just want to read a value on the native element, for instance const top = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

Comment: @abyrne85 I'm also curious, should we use the renderer if we just want to read the element.

Comment: @abyrne85, @calbear47 No, there is no need to. `Renderer2`
provides a API to manipulate native elements in platform agnostic manner. Meaning it's releasing you from direct DOM access and allowing you operate on it in abstract way. But as long as you only read and not changing anything you can use native element directly (if access to them is supported) or provide custom `Renderer2` implementation with features you are missing. Actually Angular doesn't provide any support (except `ElementRef` and [events](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen)) to get anything from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it doing this way:

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div #el></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const h1 = this.renderer.createElement('h1');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello world');

    this.renderer.appendChild(h1, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, div);
  }
}
```