# Get the index of child div in enclosing divs. Not list

Tags: javascript

I am building an Angular 7 app.
I want to get the "index" or row of a certain div within a parent div.

**My markup looks like this:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id="1" />
  <div class="item" data-id="2" />
  <div class="item" data-id="2" />
  <div class="item" data-id="3" />
</div>
```

I know I can easily do it if the markup looked like below but I don´t want to use a list if I can avoid it.

```
<ul class="container">
 <li class="item" data-id="1" />
 <li class="item" data-id="2" />
 <li class="item" data-id="2" />
 <li class="item" data-id="3" />
</ul>
```

Basically I know the data-id so I want to select that and then get the index belonging to it.

How can I do this in vanilla javascript (not using jQuery)?

Comment: all index or some ?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the difference between the DIV and the UL version? If you say you knew how to do it for the latter, are you referring to any angular-specific methods that only exist for UL elements, or anything like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658021/jquery-index-in-vanilla-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) API

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div.container');

const items = [...container.querySelectorAll('div.item')];

console.log(items);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" />
  <div class="item" />
  <div class="item" />
  <div class="item" />
</div>
```

For Angular, it's completely different. Provide a sandbox and your actual code, because there is several options to do that in the framework. Until then, I have removed the `Angular` tag.

Comment: This is not the "Angular" way.

Comment: @Bardr `How can I do this in vanilla javascript (not using jQuery)?`, and in my answer, `For Angular, it's completely different. Provide a sandbox and your actual code, because there is several options to do that in the framework.`. At some point, you gotta learn to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelector` to get elements by their attribute values like this:

```
// if you want the item with data-id=2
document.querySelector("[data-id='2']")
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m6sfruqb/) for a working example

Comment: This is not the "Angular" way.

Comment: he asked *How can I do this in vanilla javascript (not using jQuery)?*

Comment: *I am building an __Angular__ 7 app* I think that he wants to build *__Angular__ app* in *__Angular__ way*.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the "index" or row of a certain div within a parent div.

You can try the following way:

```js
function getIndex(dId){
  var list = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container .item'));
  var idx = list.map(function(el, i){
              var d = el.getAttribute('data-id');
              if(d == dId)
                return i;
            }).filter(i => i != undefined);  
  return idx;
}
console.log(getIndex("1"));
console.log(getIndex("2"));
console.log(getIndex("3"));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id="1" />
  <div class="item" data-id="2" />
  <div class="item" data-id="2" />
  <div class="item" data-id="3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkapj3)? Use `ViewChild` directive to get the container, then use `childNodes` property of this element to get children nodes. From that you can get everything you want about child node (eg. `data-id` attribute value).

Comment: This is not the proper Angular way.

Comment: `@ViewChildren` for several divs. If he has 700 divs, `@ViewChild` isn't maintainable.

Comment: @trichetriche Using `@ViewChild` I'm getting only the container. Not all child nodes.

Comment: And you use vanillaJS to request the children. You shouldn't touch the DOM yourself with Angular, but rather use the renderer and element references to query your elements.

Comment: As you see I'm using `ViewChild` directive to get the container (not `document`). Also, as long as I'm only reading from `ElementRef` there is nothing wrong about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654783/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-native-element-in-angular-using-renderer2/49655041#comment95949999_49655041